# Implement RCTEventEmitter in Swift but receive exception for bridge is not set

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native

I am trying to implement an event emitter for React Native in Swift so that I can reuse it across some of my native modules. However, when I send event natively from iOS, I received the following error

```
Bridge is not set. This is probably because you've explicitly synthesized the bridge in MyEventEmitter, even though it's inherited from RCTEventEmitter.
```

```c
/// MyEventEmitter.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyEventEmitter, RCTEventEmitter)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(supportedEvents)

@end
```

Implementation in Swift:

```swift
import Foundation

@objc(MyEventEmitter)
class MyEventEmitter: RCTEventEmitter {

    public static let shared = MyEventEmitter()

    override func supportedEvents() -> [String]! {
        return [
            ... // my event list
        ]
    }
}
```

In my native swift code, I initialized the emiter by

```swift
private let eventEmitter: MyEventEmitter = .shared

// send event
self.eventEmitter.sendEvent(withName: "someEvent", body: nil)
```

I also put `<React/RCTBridgeModule.h>` and `<React/RCTEventEmitter.h>` inside my bridging header.

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 13):

The problem I found was that you must not instantiate the `MyEventEmitter` yourself aka in `public static let shared = MyEventEmitter()`

You should rather override the `init` method and assign `self` to `shared`

```
import Foundation

@objc(MyEventEmitter)
class MyEventEmitter: RCTEventEmitter {

    public static var shared:MyEventEmitter?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        MyEventEmitter.shared = self
    }

    override func supportedEvents() -> [String]! {
        return [
            ... // my event list
        ]
    }
}
```

This is because RN will instantiate the object itself already and assign the bridge, whereas when you are doing it yourself the bridge will not be assigned.